# Google App Engine + Google Drive cache error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, cookies

I don't know why my project show the next cookie error. Could someone help me?

```
PATH

->test

     ->lib
     ->public
     ->templates
     - app.yaml
     - main.py
     - client_secrets.json
     - session-secret (python -c "import os;print os.urandom(64)" > session.secret)
```

When I use my App Engine Launcher (release: "1.7.5") and check out my localhost web page

I chose my Google account to add permissions in accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?service....... (redirect) and then accept conditions of the scopes

[image: IMAGE_SCOPES]

The log console shows the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)

  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)

  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)

  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()

  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)

  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\pruebasDocs\main.py", line 320, in get
    creds = self.GetCodeCredentials()

  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\pruebasDocs\main.py", line 194, in GetCodeCredentials
    session.set_secure_cookie(name='userid', value=userid)

  File "lib\sessions.py", line 160, in set_secure_cookie
    self.set_cookie(name, value, expires_days=expires_days, **kwargs)

  File "lib\sessions.py", line 141, in set_cookie
    self.response.headers._headers.append(('Set-Cookie', str(vals.OutputString(None))))

**AttributeError: ResponseHeaders instance has no attribute '_headers'**


lo.....t:8080/?code=4/00VfZ4DJ8d0P99v1kwn0yjBofcbq.gn6ceL8RBx0XYKs_1NgQtmXj_6WohwI
```

MAIN.PY

```
def GetCodeCredentials(self):
# Other frameworks use different API to get a query parameter.
code = self.request.get('code')
if not code:
  # returns None to indicate that no code was passed from Google Drive.
  return None

# Auth flow is a controller that is loaded with the client information,
# including client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri etc
oauth_flow = self.CreateOAuthFlow()

# Perform the exchange of the code. If there is a failure with exchanging
# the code, return None.
try:
  creds = oauth_flow.step2_exchange(code)
except FlowExchangeError:
  return None

# Create an API service that can use the userinfo API. Authorize it with our
# credentials that we gained from the code exchange.
users_service = CreateService('oauth2', 'v2', creds)

# Make a call against the userinfo service to retrieve the user's information.
# In this case we are interested in the user's "id" field.
userid = users_service.userinfo().get().execute().get('id')

# Store the user id in the user's cookie-based session.
session = sessions.LilCookies(self, SESSION_SECRET)
session.set_secure_cookie(name='userid', value=userid)
```

SESSIONS.PY

```
    # output all their cookies to the headers at once before a response flush.
for vals in new_cookie.values():
  self.response.headers._headers.append(('Set-Cookie', vals.OutputString(None)))
```

Comment: Use the `{}`, not `""` button to format code properly.

Comment: thanks ... but i still have an error

Comment: That wasn't intended to fix your error; just to make your question readable.

Comment: and could you help me fixing the error?

Comment: Does this still happen in latest version?

Comment: I've got App Engine Launcher (release: "1.7.5") Python 2.7 and using oauth2 (1.5) api version: 1 . But what do you refer which  with latest version?

Comment: Can someone help me? i'm still having issues.

Comment: I have commented  #session.set_secure_cookie(name='userid', value=userid) and i can continue working.. but the error of cookies isn't solved